# Where is the dialogs' source code in CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, ckeditor, fckeditor

Could somebody with experience in CKEditor give me some pointers where to edit the structure and contents of the "insert Link" and other dialogs?

At the moment, I want to modify the width of the link window, so that changing tabs doesn't result in the dialog being resized every time.

I'm sifting through both the minified and unminified versions, as well as the documentation, but am having a really hard time getting into this thing. Any hints or documentation links would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, CKEditor's documentation is good for something after all: 
[FCKeditor 3.x | Design and Architecture | Dialog system](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_3.x/Design_and_Architecture/Dialog_System)